# Voltage, capacitance, charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, capacitance

We know charge is proportional to voltage

Q=CV

C=Q/V

Voltage is work done per unit charge and capacitance is charge per unit voltage (i.e how much charge is there when 1v of voltage is applied)
But volatge is work done by unit charge , so there always be 1c of charge when 1v is applied

Answer (score 1):

"But volatge is work done by unit charge , so there always be 1c of charge when 1v is applied"

You have misunderstood "voltage is work done per unit charge". It means that if we take a charge, $q$, from point A to point B, and the work done on the charge by the electric field in the region between A and B is $W$, then the voltage, $V$, between A and B is defined as $V=\frac Wq$.

$\frac Wq$ is the work done on the charge *per unit charge.* **It does not imply any particular value for *q*.** The work done on a charge of 2$\mu$C taken from A to B will be twice as much as the work done on a charge of 1$\mu$C taken from A to B, so we'll get the same value for the voltage whatever charge we take from A to B.

Note also that the charge $q$ (sometimes called a 'test charge') used in this definition of voltage has no relationship to the charges, ±*Q*, on the plates of the capacitor.

Comment: Can you pls explain me , what is capacitance briefly

Comment: Charge stored on either plate of a capacitor divided by the voltage between the plates (that is =/). [For a given capacitor (that is a given configuration of plates and dielectric) $Q$ is proportional to $V$. $C$ is the proportionality constant.] But don't you have a textbook that explains these things?

Comment: Sorry for asking you

Comment: Nothing to apologise for. I was just curious that you needed to ask about what capacitance means. It's well explained in all relevant textbooks that I've seen. In my opinion, voltage is a much more difficult idea, but one that you need to understand well – and *before* you start to study capacitors.